# Where did `cmdtest` come from?

Tags: package-management, 22.10

Anyone know how to find out where a package came from?  Or if it is a core package for Ubuntu?

I was trying to get `yarn install` working and following the docs did not work, it failed on `$ readlink /usr/bin/yarn` because the binary was a python script and not a symlink.

Turned out I had `cmdtest` installed for some reason.  Nuking that with `$ sudo apt remove --purge cmdtest` allowed me to get `yarn` working, but I am curious why I had it installed in the first place and if I broke any other packages that depended on it.

How can I find out where `cmdtest` came from and if any packages still depend on it?

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind!  If you write that up as an answer I can mark it.  Playing with it i am struggling to see where I can find dependency trees or something.  I was also curious if Ubuntu did any logging on when packages were installed.

Comment: @Chris `apt`'s log files are in `/var/log/apt/`, IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/cmdtest) nothing depends on it so this will be manually installed it yourself. Since you could purge it through apt and if you did not remove the log files for apt it will be in `/var/log/apt/history.log*` (that log file gets compressed).

Search for cmdtest can be done with:

```
cd /var/apt/log/
grep cmdtest history.log
zgrep cmdtest history.log.*.gz
```